# Better way to write case statement to optimize code?

Tags: sql

Currently, I have a query with multiple case when statements which is causing my code to run an excessively long time. I was wondering if there was any better way to write and optimize this code.

```
SELECT equipment_id 

, CASE  WHEN (SELECT LOWER(to_char(equipment_type)) FROM equipment_type WHERE equipment_type_id = 100001 AND equipment_id = e.equipment_id) = '3qwe' 
  THEN 'Table 1.1-2, ' 
  WHEN (SELECT LOWER(to_char(equipment_type)) FROM equipment_type WHERE equipment_type_id = 100001 AND equipment_id = e.equipment_id) = '6qwe' 
  THEN 'Table 1.2-2, ' 
  WHEN (SELECT LOWER(to_char(equipment_type)) FROM equipment_type WHERE equipment_type_id = 100001 AND equipment_id = e.equipment_id) = '6qre' 
  THEN 'Table 1.2-3, '
  ELSE NULL 
  END table_number
  
, CASE  WHEN (SELECT LOWER(to_char(equipment_type)) FROM equipment_type WHERE equipment_type_id = 14 AND equipment_id = e.equipment_id) = 'gas' 
  THEN 'Gas Powered ' 
  WHEN (SELECT LOWER(to_char(equipment_type)) FROM equipment_type WHERE equipment_type_id = 14 AND equipment_id = e.equipment_id) = 'electric' 
  THEN 'Electric Powered '
  ELSE NULL 
  END power_type
  
, CASE  WHEN (SELECT LOWER(to_char(equipment_type)) FROM equipment_type WHERE equipment_type_id = 100001 AND equipment_id = e.equipment_id) = '3qwe' 
  THEN '3-round, west' 
  WHEN (SELECT LOWER(to_char(equipment_type)) FROM equipment_type WHERE equipment_type_id = 100001 AND equipment_id = e.equipment_id) = '6qwe' 
  THEN '6 round, west '  
  WHEN (SELECT LOWER(to_char(equipment_type)) FROM equipment_type WHERE equipment_type_id = 100001 AND equipment_id = e.equipment_id) = '6qre' 
  THEN '6-round, east' 
  WHEN (SELECT LOWER(to_char(equipment_type)) FROM equipment_type WHERE equipment_type_id = 100001 AND equipment_id = e.equipment_id) = 'n/a'    
  THEN '(<= 200 mg)' 
  ELSE NULL 
  END  rating_class

 
FROM equipment e
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check out [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Following these guidelines (in this case, specifically by providing CML and sample data, with expected output) would allow people to more easily answer your question.

Comment: This definitely has the look of something where we could help optimize (having sample data is important... and showing expected output is important before most people here will invest time in a closer look.)

Comment: Please tag your question with the DBMS you are using and update your question with the EXPLAIN PLAN for your query. However, I'm guessing that just having a normal join to equipment_type, removing all the selects from your case statements and then aggregating the case statements, grouping by equipment_id, would perform better

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you're using subqueries in your case statements, you can get the same output without them, and this could be the source of your performance issues.

It's also extremely unclear exactly what the structure of each table and its data is, so you should provide DDL for the two tables and representative example data if you want accurate and complete answers.

However, assuming some table structure and dummy data:

```
create table #equipment
(
    equipment_id int
)

create table #equipment_type
(
    equipment_id int,
    equipment_type_id int,
    equipment_type varchar(20)
)

insert into #equipment values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6)

insert into #equipment_type values
(1, 100001, '3qwe'),
(2, 100001, '6qwe'),
(3, 100001, '6qre'),
(4, 14, 'gas'),
(5, 14, 'electric'),
(6, 100001, 'n/a')
```

This query will return the same results:

```
select
    e.equipment_id,
    case 
        when et.equipment_type_id = 100001 and et.equipment_type = '3qwe' then 'Table 1.1-2'
        when et.equipment_type_id = 100001 and et.equipment_type = '6qwe' then 'Table 1.2-2'
        when et.equipment_type_id = 100001 and et.equipment_type = '6qre' then 'Table 1.2-3'
        else null
    end as table_number,
    case
        when et.equipment_type_id = 14 and et.equipment_type = 'gas' then 'Gas Powered'
        when et.equipment_type_id = 14 and et.equipment_type = 'electric' then 'Electric Powered'
        else null
    end as power_type,
    case
        when et.equipment_type_id = 100001 and et.equipment_type = '3qwe' then '3-round, west'
        when et.equipment_type_id = 100001 and et.equipment_type = '6qwe' then '6 round, west'
        when et.equipment_type_id = 100001 and et.equipment_type = '6qre' then '6-round east'
        when et.equipment_type_id = 100001 and et.equipment_type = 'n/a' then '(<= 200 mg)'
        else null
    end as rating_class
from #equipment e
join #equipment_type et on e.equipment_id = et.equipment_id
```

If - as has been alluded to in comments - you can have multiple records in the `equipment_type` table for the same `equipment_id`, then you need to explain how you want that scenario to surface in your results - multiple records per `equipment_id`, or some logic to determine which values should be returned for each field.

Comment: how is your solution going to work when, based on the information in the question, there are multiple records in equipment_type with the same equipment_id?

Comment: There is no equipment_type column in equipment table. It is in equipment_type table. This doesn't cover multiple types...

Comment: Yes, I see now, got lost in the subqueries - will rewrite now with a join, but the principle is the same.

Comment: It's actually really unclear what the table structure is here, with the lack of consistent alias usage in the query in the question. If the OP could provide DML for the two tables, it would be much easier to answer accurately.

Comment: @NickW - the question uses subqueries in the `SELECT` clause, so if those are returning multiple values for a given record, then the query will already fail as-is, not just run slowly. If the OP wants to handle the scenario you describe, they need to provide DDL, sample data and expected output.

Comment: @3N1GM4 Your new code is almost the same as mine, but I'm afraid you missed dummy data again. I'd say that same equipment_id has several rows in equipment_type table defining things like type_id 14 "powered by", lets say 15 could be "number of doors", then 16 could be "color" and so on. Thats why I think that result should be further processed. Can't be sure but that is how I see the op's code. Thanks for correcting the typos in my answer, btw.

Answer (score 1):

Too many subqueries. You could select what you need from equipment_type table once and join it to equipment table.

Something like below - didn't test it, though, but you will get the picture...

```sql
Select  e.EQUIPMENT_ID, 
        CASE WHEN et.EQUIPMENT_TYPE_ID = 100001 And et.EQUIPMENT_TYPE = '3qwe' THEN 'Table 1.1-2, ' 
             WHEN et.EQUIPMENT_TYPE_ID = 100001 And et.EQUIPMENT_TYPE = '6qwe' THEN 'Table 1.2-2, ' 
             WHEN et.EQUIPMENT_TYPE_ID = 100001 And et.EQUIPMENT_TYPE = '6qre' THEN 'Table 1.2-3, '
        END "TABLE_NUMBER",
        --
        CASE WHEN et.EQUIPMENT_TYPE_ID = 14 And et.EQUIPMENT_TYPE = 'gas' THEN 'Gas Powered ' 
             WHEN et.EQUIPMENT_TYPE_ID = 14 And et.EQUIPMENT_TYPE = 'electric' THEN 'Electric Powered '
        END "POWER_TYPE",
        --
        CASE WHEN et.EQUIPMENT_TYPE_ID = 100001 And et.EQUIPMENT_TYPE = '3qwe' THEN '3-round' 
             WHEN et.EQUIPMENT_TYPE_ID = 100001 And et.EQUIPMENT_TYPE = '6qwe' THEN '6-round, west'  
             WHEN et.EQUIPMENT_TYPE_ID = 100001 And et.EQUIPMENT_TYPE = '6qre' THEN '6-round, east' 
             WHEN et.EQUIPMENT_TYPE_ID = 100001 And et.EQUIPMENT_TYPE = 'n/a'  THEN '(<= 200 mg)' 
        END  "RATING_CLASS"
From EQUIPMENT e
Inner Join 
    (   Select Lower(To_Char(EQUIPMENT_TYPE)) "EQUIPMENT_TYPE", EQUIPMENT_TYPE_ID
        From EQUIPMENT_TYPE 
    ) et ON(et.EQUIPMENT_ID = e.EQUIPMENT_ID)
```

Btw, there is no sample data provided to test it (the result should probably be aggregated to get rid of nulls) and there is no DBMS tag. The syntax used in this answer is Oracle.